# create invoice and email in Magento

Tags: email, magento, invoice

I want to automate the creation of invoice and email in Magento. Invoice creation seems to work but I am having getting the email part working...

```
 Mage::app();       
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);

    try 
    {
        if(!$order->canInvoice())           {   
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
        }

        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

        if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
        }

        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
        $invoice->register();
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
        $transactionSave->save();
    }       
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: see this link http://www.marcogermani.it/2012/02/06/magento-snippet-disabilitare-lauto-invoice-di-paypal/ it might help Rachel

Comment: you might have to translate it with google translate

Answer (score 1):

I know my reaction is kinda late but for others who find this page:

You need to add the code for sending the email.
Do this after the register line:

---

```
$invoice->register();
$invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$invoice->sendEmail();
```

---

setCustomerNoteNotify is used to say if the customer has to get the email.

setIsInProcess will change the order state to processing